# How imwrite in loop write many different images in Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, image-processing, octave

In loop when I generate images I use this string

```
imwrite(IWindow, gray(256), 'plane', 'tif');
```

to write the image of this iteration.
In this loop I have z iterator.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: How can I substitute my z value in every single image name? Now image name is 'plane'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that-

```
 for z=1:num
      fname=sprintf ('plane%d.tif', z);
      imwrite (IWindow, gray (256), fname);
 end
```